# Parsing and pushing nested json object in ios

Tags: ios, json, nested

I am working with nested Json object in ios and the problem is am not able to parse it . Can anyone help me out through this . I have followed many links but dint proved to be fruitful.

Json File is as follow :

{

```
"taskList":[
    {
        "taskId":101,
        "taskName":"Survey Task1",
        "details":"australian map for field partners",
        "dropDate":"2014-11-26",
        "dueDate":"2014-11-27",
        "supervisorId":12,
        "supervisorContactInfo":"54543",
        "status":"assigned",
        "formList":[
            {
                "formId":"CAFvodafone",
                "formName":"CAF vodafone",

            },
            {
                "formId":"CAF",
                "formName":"CAF",

            },
            {
                "formId":"telenore_cdk",
                "formName":"telenore cdk",

            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "taskId":102,
        "taskName":"Survey Task2",
        "details":"australian map for field partners",
        "dropDate":"2014-11-26",
        "dueDate":"2014-11-27",
        "supervisorId":12,
        "supervisorContactInfo":"54543",
        "status":"assigned",
        "formList":[
            {
                "formId":"Salesform",
                "formName":"Sales form",

            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "taskId":111,
        "taskName":"Survey Task8",
        "details":"australian map for field partners",
        "dropDate":"2014-11-29",
        "dueDate":"2014-12-20",
        "supervisorId":12,
        "supervisorContactInfo":"54543",
        "status":"assigned",
        "formList":[
            {
                "formId":"CAF",
                "formName":"CAF",

            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "taskId":118,
        "taskName":"Survey Task8",
        "details":"australian map for field partners",
        "dropDate":"2014-11-29",
        "dueDate":"2014-12-20",
        "supervisorId":12,
        "supervisorContactInfo":"54543",
        "status":"assigned",
        "formList":[
            {
                "formId":"CAFvodafone",
                "formName":"CAF vodafone",

            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "taskId":113,
        "taskName":"Survey Task8",
        "details":"australian map for field partners",
        "dropDate":"2014-11-29",
        "dueDate":"2014-12-20",
        "supervisorId":12,
        "supervisorContactInfo":"54543",
        "status":"assigned",
        "formList":[
            {
                "formId":"CAF",
                "formName":"CAF",

            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "taskId":112,
        "taskName":"Survey Task8",
        "details":"australian map for field partners",
        "dropDate":"2014-11-29",
        "dueDate":"2014-12-20",
        "supervisorId":12,
        "supervisorContactInfo":"54543",
        "status":"assigned",
        "formList":[
            {
                "formId":"CAF",
                "formName":"CAF",

            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "taskId":116,
        "taskName":"Survey Task8",
        "details":"australian map for field partners",
        "dropDate":"2014-11-29",
        "dueDate":"2014-12-20",
        "supervisorId":12,
        "supervisorContactInfo":"54543",
        "status":"assigned",
        "formList":[
            {
                "formId":"CAFvodafone",
                "formName":"CAF vodafone",

            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Author: Roop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from your json dictionary

```
id arrayTrack = json[@"taskList"];

    if ([arrayTrack isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]){ // check it array or not

        for (id trackDictionary in arrayTrack) {

            if ([trackDictionary isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]){ //check it Dictionary or not

                trackId = trackDictionary[@"taskId"];
// Like this you can fetch other key values...
            }


        }

    }
```

i think this will help you :)

Answer (score 0):

You try this way parse json data

```
NSLog(@"%@",[[[yourjsonDictionary objectForKey:@"taskList"] objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"taskName"]);
```

json response return dictionary first get value from dictionary

```
[yourjsonDictionary objectForKey:@"taskList"] // this statement return array
```

You get first key and value in array and get array value like this way

```
[[yourjsonDictionary objectForKey:@"taskList"] objectAtIndex:0] // return first array element
```

get 0 element value

```
[[[yourjsonDictionary objectForKey:@"taskList"] objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"taskName"] //return task name

[[[yourjsonDictionary objectForKey:@"taskList"] objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"taskId"] // return task Id
```

Get Nested formList data

```
[[[[[yourjsonDictionary objectForKey:@"taskList"] objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"formList"] objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"formName"] // return form name
```

OR

```
NSLog(@"%@",yourjsonDictionary[@"taskList"][0][@"taskName"]); // print task name
```